# I am unable to connect to my SQL Server 2008 on Remote Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am Trying to connect to my SQL Server but I keep getting this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

This is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDB"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Server=Usman-PC\SQLExpress; Database=myDB; Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have google for solution and tried many things but keep getting this error. 
I was developing accounts app and now it is time for deployment on production server. Please somebody help me.

Below are my settings

- Computer name: Usman-PC
- WorkGroup: USMAN-SERVER
- Ip address: 192.168.0.1
- Server Name: `Usman-PC\SQLExpress`
- Instance Name: `SQLEXPRESS`

What I have tried:

- I have looked at connection setting in Server Properties and they are good.
- I also have checked and server is running.
- I also have enabled TCP/IP and set the port to 1433.
- I also have added new rule for port 1433 in firewall.

I am also able to transfer files between both computers.

Comment: try to ping 'Usman-PC' also try to do a telnet to Usman-PC 1433

Comment: Check if all the relevant Services, i.e SQL Server Browser Service, are running

Comment: Try turning named pipes off and on

Comment: I ping Usman-PC and received: Ping Statistics for fe80::a0d0:2214:9598:23f6%11: Packs: Sent = 4, Received = 4 Lost = 0<0% loss>.

Comment: Name Pipes are on

Comment: User6144226: I checked the services and running.